# C#, more efficient way of adding points to a chart series?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a while loop that adds new points to an empty chart series:

First I clear the old points:

```
points.Clear()
```

Then I use this in my loop to add a point:

```
AddXY(the_x_value, the_y_value);
```

But is there another way I can do it? Could I add the x/y data to two arrays or lists and then add them all in one go?

Some sort of:

```
AddXY(x_values_array, y_values_array);
```

Comment: you can use `chart.Series[0].Points.AddXy(object, object[])` overload which allows you to supply array of y values for one x value.

Comment: also, what is the format of data you're using to fill chart data? `DataTable`, `Tuple, `List<>`...? I'm asking to make an example of how to convert it and pass to `Points` collection...